# i am doing sclera based authentication project ,i need to perform sclera vessel pattern enhancement using gabor filter ,help me to modify belowcode

Tags: matlab

I am doing project on sclera based authentication. I have done sclera area detection now I want to do sclera veins enhancement. I tried that using Gabor filter (I have included the code below) but it enhances edges of an eye rather than sclera veins. What changes should I make so that only sclera vessel pattern will be enhanced.

- the first  image which is given below is the sclera area detected image and;
- the second image is the desired output after applying Gabor filter for vessel pattern enhancement.

Here is code for my Gabor filter:

```
theta=pi/2; lambda =3.5; gamma=0.3; sigma=2.8; psi=0;

sigma_x = sigma; sigma_y = sigma/gamma;

nstds = 5; 
xmax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*cos(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*sin(theta))); 
xmax = ceil(max(1,xmax));
ymax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*sin(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*cos(theta))); 
ymax = ceil(max(1,ymax)); xmin = -xmax; ymin = -ymax; 
[x,y] = meshgrid(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax);

x_theta=x*cos(theta)+y*sin(theta); y_theta=-x*sin(theta)+y*cos(theta);

gb= exp(-.5*(x_theta.^2/sigma_x^2+y_theta.^2/sigma_y^2)).*cos(2*pi/lambda*x_theta+psi);

%subplot(3,2,5); %imshow(gb); %title('theta=...'); %imagesc(gb); %colormap(gray); %title('theta=...');

image_double=im2double(K);
 figure,subplot(2,2,1); 
%imshow(image_double); 
%figure(3);
 filtered1 = conv2(image_double,gb); 
%subplot(3,2,5); 
imshow(filtered1); 
title('gabor filter when theta is pi/2'); 
%colormap(gray); 
%title('theta=pi/2');
```

[image: sclera area detected image]

[image: desired output after applying gabor filter for vessel pattern enhncement is shown in the image]

Comment: You'll likely get much better help if you provide some sample images so the users here have a better idea of what you're trying to process.

Comment: Just ignore the border where the black white contrast of the original image is so strong. This could be done for example by applying a mask and shrinking it a few pixels.